# Limiting conections to an Subversion server based on IP

Tags: windows, svn

I want to controls which IP addresses can connect to a subversion repository (svnserve) on a windows box.

Is it possible to configure svnserve itself to do this?
If not what would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about svnserve, but firewall will do the job.

Comment: svnserve doesn't have builtin configuration to handle this, so I would recommend using a firewall for this task. (The other option is using apache for the repository hosting, which has configuration settings for these tasks)

Comment: Cheers, I just wanted to make sure that there was not some built in functionality I was missing somehow